# Change element id and behaviour on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a button that changes its id on click, and its name. It changes only when I click the first time on "Start!". After that it is not working and I don't know why.

```
$("#start").click(function(){
  $(this).attr("id", "stop");
  $(this).html("Stop!");
});

$("#stop").click(function(){
  $(this).attr("id", "start");
  $(this).html("Start!");
});
```

Comment: Try .prop() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$('#stop')` selector can't works because you have no html element with the id `stop` when you run it. So you have 2 choices : Use only one listener or use the delegation system of jQuery.

One listener :

```
$('#start').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        id = $this.attr('id');

    if (id == 'start') {
        $this.attr('id', 'stop');
        $this.html('Stop!');
    } else {
        $this.attr('id', 'start');
        $this.html('Start!');
    }
});
```

Delegation system :

```
$(document.body).on('click', "#start", function(){
  $(this).attr("id", "stop");
  $(this).html("Stop!");
});

$(document.body).on('click', "#stop", function(){
  $(this).attr("id", "start");
  $(this).html("Start!");
});
```

Anyway, mplungjan is right. Changing the ID is not a good idea. You should use a CSS class for that.

Comment: I agree - I am right :))) I doubt example 1 will work without the example 2 in place

Answer (score 4):

Changing ID is not a good idea.

have a button and toggle the class and content

```js
$("#toggle").on("click",function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("stop");
  $(this).html($(this).is(".stop")?"Stop":"Start"); // if ($(this).is(".stop")) {} else {} 
});
```

```css
.stop { background-color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">Start</button>
```